# What's the bug with a possible wrapper function of realloc C function?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, realloc

I like to know the possible bug in the following possible wrapper function of the realloc C function:

```
void reallocX(void** ptr, size_t size)
{
    void *new_ptr = realloc(*ptr, size);
    if (new_ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (new_ptr != *ptr)
        {
            *ptr = new_ptr;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Help! realloc returned NULL!\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

.

I know that it is based in the possible wrapper function of the malloc C function, that is:

```
void *
mallocX (size_t nbytes)
{
  void *ptr;
  ptr = malloc (nbytes);
  if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf( "Help! malloc returned NULL!\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

. This malloc C function wrapper function is based on the "mallocc" C function of [this webpage](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It has a bug because?

Comment: It seems it's *someone else* how likes to know that.

Comment: @iharob It does have a bug.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A null-pointer return value from `realloc` may indicate either:

1. That the function did not allocate storage.
2. That the size parameter was zero and the memory was deallocated.

Your code covers the first possibility, but not the second.  A null return value can be valid, indicating that deallocation of a memory block completed succesfully.  Signalling an error under these conditions is a bug.

**Note this applies for C90 C++98**

As noted in the comments, passing a size parameter of 0 is implementation specific in C99/C11 C++11.

Comment: I would consider passing a size of 0 to `realloc` to be a bug to begin with. Different implementations vary, often in non-conforming ways, with regard to how they handle this case. `realloc` to size 0 is **not** specified to be the same as `free` except on implementations where `malloc(0)` returns a null pointer, but some implementations wrongly make it the same, and there's no clean way to handle the difference (to determine whether it's an error or an expected behavior). Just avoid doing this.

Comment: See definition of [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/).

Comment: @R.. Thanks for pointing that out.  I've added a note regarding the different standards.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one bug; this line:

```
    if (new_ptr != *ptr)
```

invokes undefined behavior. Any use of the old pointer, especially comparison with the new one, after `realloc` succeeds, is forbidden. You need to make the assignment unconditionally.

Further, while this is not an internal bug, the external API is misdesigned and error-prone. Often the type of the caller's pointer will not be `void *` but some other pointer type like `char *` or `struct foo *`, and you'll have users doing:

```
reallocX((void **)&myptr, size);
```

This causes your function to invoke undefined behavior via aliasing violations (at the very least; possibly also out-of-bound writes if different pointer types vary in size/representation) because it's accessing a `void *` object at an address that does not point to a `void *` object but to some other type of pointer object.

These kinds of wrappers are simply harmful and need to be rejected. There's no way to do them right/safely.